# Preserved linear independence of vectors

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been considering the following problem.

> Consider linearly independent vectors $a_1, a_2 ... a_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $b_1, b_2, ... b_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $|b_i|< \delta $ for all $i$ from $1$ to $k$, then $(a_1+b_1), (a_2+b_2), ... (a_k+b_k)$ are also linearly independent.

I believe it relates to the previously proven result that the set of full rank matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{kxn}$ form an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{kxn}$. However, I'm not entirely sure how to apply this proposition in practice.

I would be grateful for any guidance here.

Comment: What does full rank have to do with linear independence of the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the maps $T, S:\mathbb{R} ^{k} \to \mathbb{R} ^{n} $, given by $$T(e_{i}) =a_{i}, S(e_{i}) =a_{i} +b_{i} $$, where $e_{i}, i=1,\cdots k$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R} ^{k} $, the assumption that $a_{i} $ are linearly independent is equivalent to $Rank(T) =k$, Since u had the result that the set of full rank maps is open, this ensures the existence of  $\delta$, such that $S, T$ has the same rank (i.e $a_{i} +b_{i}$ are linearly independent), whenever $\lvert b_{i} \rvert <\delta$, because $$\lvert \lvert S-T\rvert \rvert =\sup_{\lvert x\rvert=1}\lvert (S-T)(x) \rvert =\sup_{\lvert x\rvert=1}\lvert (S-T)(\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_{i} e_{i} ) \rvert \leq(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lvert x_{i}\rvert  \lvert b_{i}) \rvert < \delta 
$$ Edit:I didn't pay attention to the specific  norm used But this doesn't change almost anything since all norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional   $$\lvert \lvert S-T\rvert \rvert=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lvert \lvert b_{i}\rvert \rvert^{2}}$$ So it suffices to pick $b_{i}$ to satisfy $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lvert \lvert b_{i}\rvert \rvert^{2}} < \delta$$

Comment: @FD_bfa I edited my answer by adding the case corresponding to the norm u specified in a comment.